# Cost function in cv. glm for a fitted logistic model when cutoff value of the model is not 0.5

Tags: r, cross-validation, logistic-regression

I have a logistic model fitted with the following R function:

```
glmfit<-glm(formula, data, family=binomial)
```

A  reasonable cutoff value in order to get a good data classification (or confusion matrix) with the fitted model is 0.2 instead of the mostly used 0.5.

And I want to use the `cv.glm` function with the fitted model:

```
cv.glm(data, glmfit, cost, K)
```

Since the response in the fitted model is a binary variable an appropriate cost function is (obtained from "Examples" section of ?cv.glm):

```
cost <- function(r, pi = 0) mean(abs(r-pi) > 0.5)
```

As I have a cutoff value of 0.2, can I apply this standard cost function or should I define a different one and how?

Comment: Might be better on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks. I will post it there.